# How to make textarea look like notebook?

Tags: css, html, forms

I want the user to feel like they are writing on notebook paper while inputting into a textarea. How may I do this?

Comment: HTML/CSS questions are a better fit on [Doctype](http://doctype.com)

Answer (score 1):

Several ways. You can use a notepaper background on a text area. So then it feels like the user is writing on paper. Then, using either @font-face or cufon, find a suitable hand writing text (I like Biro, especially in blue) and then assign the font type to the text area as this font.

I think this is the easiest way to achieve what you want.